# How to resolve "Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation." for reverse linked list?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I am working on reverse linked list on Windows 10 Pro (64 bit) with Visual Studio Community 2019. I would like to know how to resolve the error I get as below. I get below error in the `while` loop in the member function `reverse()` in the `class List`

(*Please assume the list is already prepared like contiguous integer e.g. 0,1,2,3,4,5)
Could you please anyone give me some advice? Thank you in advance.

*Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation.
**current** was 0xDDDDDDDD.*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

template <class Data>

class Node
{
public:
    Node* next;
    Data data;
};

template <class Data>

class List
{

private:
    Node<Data>* head;
    Node<Data>* tail;
    int count;

public:
    //constructor
    List()
    {
        count = 0;
        head = nullptr;
        tail = nullptr;
    }


    int size()
    {
        return count;
    }


    void msg_empty_list()
    {
        cout << "The list is not modified since it is empty." << endl;
    }


    int push_back(Data data)
    {
        Node<Data>* node = new Node<Data>;
        node->data = data;
        node->next = nullptr;

        if (head == nullptr)
        {
            head = node;
            tail = node;
        }
        else if (head != nullptr)
        {
            tail->next = node;
            tail = tail->next;
        }

        count++;
        return count;
    }


    int push_front(Data data)
    {
        Node<Data>* node = new Node<Data>;
        node->data = data;
        node->next = nullptr;

        if (head == nullptr)
            head = node;
        else if (head != nullptr)
        {
            node->next = head;
            head = node;
        }

        count++;
        return count;
    }


    int pop_front(void)
    {
        if (head == nullptr)
            return -1;
        else if (head != nullptr)
        {
            Node<Data>* temp;
            temp = head;
            head = head->next;
            delete temp;

            count--;
            return count;
        }
    }


    int pop_back(void)
    {
        if (head == nullptr)
            return -1;
        else if (head != nullptr)
        {
            Node<Data>* temp = head;
            while (temp->next != tail)
                temp = temp->next;

            delete tail;
            tail = temp;

            count--;
            return count;
        }
    }


    int remove_at(int index)
    {
        if (head == nullptr)
            return -1;
        else if (head != nullptr)
        {
            cout << "Specified index = " << index << endl;
            if (index == 0)
            {
                pop_front();
            }
            else if (index == -1)
            {
                pop_back();
            }
            Node<Data>* temp = head;
            Node<Data>* rmv;
            int countIndex = 0;

            while (countIndex < index - 1)
            {
                temp = temp->next;
                countIndex++;
            }

            rmv = temp->next;
            temp->next = temp->next->next;
            delete rmv;

            count--;
            return count;
        }
    }


    void reverse()
    {
        Node<Data>* temp = nullptr;
        Node<Data>* prev = nullptr;
        Node<Data>* current = head;

        while (current != nullptr)
        {
            temp = current->next; // where I get error "Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation. **current** was 0xDDDDDDDD."
            current->next = prev;
            prev = current;
            current = temp;
        }
        head = prev;
    }


    void print()
    {
        Node<Data>* temp = head;

        if (head == nullptr)
            return;

        for (int i = 0; i < count - 1; i++)
        {
            cout << temp->data << ", ";
            temp = temp->next;
        }

        cout << temp->data;
    }


    ~List()
    {
        Node<Data>* temp = head;

        while (temp->next != nullptr)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
            delete head;
            head = temp;
        }

    }
};


int main()
{
    Node<int> x;
    Node<bool> y;
    Node<char> n;
    List<int> list;

    //insert items into list
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        list.push_back(i);
    }

    cout << "Original list[size=" << list.size() << "]: ";
    //print the list
    list.print();
    cout << endl;

    // push a node to the beginning of the list
    cout << endl << "==> Push a node to the head" << endl;
    list.push_front(-1);
    cout << "Modified list[size=" << list.size() << "]: ";
    list.print();
    cout << endl;


    // pop the head of the list
    cout << endl << "==> Pop a node from the head" << endl;
    if (list.size() == 0)
        list.msg_empty_list();
    else
    {
        list.pop_front();
        cout << "Modified list[size=" << list.size() << "]: ";
        list.print();
        cout << endl;
    }

    /*
    // pop the tail of the list
    cout << endl << "==> Pop a node from the tail" << endl;
    if (list.size() == 0)
        list.msg_empty_list();
    else
    {
        list.pop_back();
        cout << "Modified list[size=" << list.size() << "]: ";
        list.print();
        cout << endl;
    }
    */

    // delete the node at the specified index
    cout << endl << "==> Delete the node at the specified index" << endl;
    if (list.size() == 0)
        list.msg_empty_list();
    else
    {
        list.remove_at(5);
        cout << "Modified list[size=" << list.size() << "]: ";
        list.print();
        cout << endl;
    }


    // reverse the list
    cout << endl << "==> Reverse the list" << endl;
    if (list.size() == 0)
        list.msg_empty_list();
    else
    {
        list.reverse();
        cout << "Modified list[size=" << list.size() << "]: ";
        list.print();
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `0xDDDDDDDD` (in Visual C++ Debug mode) indicates that the pointer has already been `delete`d. You did not show where you do that.

Comment: @Eugene Thank you for your comment! I didn't delete any pointer.

Comment: `Node` has no constructor. It's fields will be uninitialized. The error you see happens somewhere else, it just shows up at that line. The causes for access violations are hard to debug.

Comment: You need to show how the list was constructed. Please create a [mcve] that we could run, it should create the list and then call `reverse`. Note the word "minimal", so remove any code not needed to demonstrate the fault. Programmers often find that the act of creating such a minimal example helps them solve the problem themselves.

Comment: @PMF Thank you for your comment! Appreciate it. As for constructor for `Node` My understanding is that these three lines `Node<Data>* temp = nullptr;`, `Node<Data>* prev = nullptr;`,`Node<Data>* current = head;` are constructors.

Comment: @PMF Also I added main driver code just for your reference. Thank you!

Comment: @AdrianHHH Thank you for the comment! I read through the reference you provided [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and tried to create minimal reproducible code, but then I ran the code and the issue has gone. The reverse function worked! I dig down this issue and let me get back to you as soon as I can. I appreciate your help!

Comment: No, these are not constructors, these are initializations of local variables. Your code is never creating an instance of `Node` here. Please show the implementation of `push_back`.

Comment: Maybe saying "create" a minimal code to demonstrate the issue is misleading. What is often meant is to take the code that fails and remove unnecessary things (often replacing them with simpler code) until getting the minimal code needed to show the issue. This exercise can reveal the problem to you.

Comment: @PMF  @AdrianHHH Thank you for pointing that out! I added my functions implementations including `push_back()`. Now I guess there is an issue `// pop the tail of the list` part. If I comment out that part as I wrote above, this code runs without error, but if I include the part and run it, it generates access violation error.

Comment: @AdrianHHH Thank you for your advice. I understand the point you mentioned. :) 
I added my functions which may be related to issue as above. Now I guess there is an issue `// pop the tail of the list` part. If I comment out that part as I wrote above, this code runs without error, but if I include the part and run it, it generates access violation error. I guess there should be issue in my `pop_back()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can spot a few mistakes in your code, but let's concentrate on the `pop_back()` function:

```cpp
    int pop_back(void)
    {
        if (head == nullptr)
            return -1;
        else if (head != nullptr) // 1)
        {
            Node<Data>* temp = head;
            while (temp->next != tail) // 2)
                temp = temp->next;

            delete tail;
            tail = temp; // 3)

            count--;
            return count;
        }
    }
```

1. Please don't do this: `if (a == nullptr) {...} else if (a != nullptr) {...}` is redundant. Just leave the second `if` away. It lets a reader believe there could be a third case.
2. It may be luck that this usually works, but some of the other methods don't properly update the tail pointer, so this might never be true. Validate your `pop_front` method when there's only one element in the list. Other functions might have similar problems.
3. Here's the actual problem you're observing. You're not setting the `next` pointer of the new tail element to null, instead it points to the now deleted tail. Insert `tail->next = nullptr` after this line.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! As for #3 I quickly added the line to set the `next` pointer of the new tail to point to NULL., then it worked finally!! As for #1 and #2 I work on them later when I get back from work. Let me get back to you. Again, I appreciate your help. Hope you have a great evening!

Comment: Thank you! 1) I fixed my code. 2) As you mentioned yes it had issue in that case. So I fixed my code, too. I can't thank you enough for your support. I appreciate your help. Have a great day!